# Complex Regex getting value from string

Tags: java, regex

Here are some input samples:

1, 2, 3
'a', 'b',    'c'
'a','b','c'
1, 'a', 'b'

Strings have single quotes around them, number don't. In strings, double single quote '' (that's two times ') is the escape character for single quote '. The following also also valid input.

'this''is''one string', 1, 2
'''this'' is a weird one', 1, 2
'''''''', 1, 2

after playing around for a looong time, I ended up with something like:

```
^(\\d*|(?:(?:')([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:')))(?:(?:, *)(\\d*|(?:(?:')([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:'))))*$
```

which totally doesn't work and is not complete :)

Using Java matcher/group an example would be:
input: '''la''la', 1,3
matched groups:

- 'la'la
- 1
- 2

Note that the output string doesn't have single quotes around it but just the escaped quotes from the input.

any Regex gurus out there? thanks
PS: I'll let you know if I ever figure it out myself, still trying

Comment: I'm not clear as to what the correct output should look like. Is there likely to be more or less than three parameters per line?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match?
The values of each comma-seperated string? Including the quotes?

Comment: What about commas in strings, isn't that the real issue? Otherwise, it is simple to split by commas, and escape the string.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response.

The number of params can be 0 or more.
the sample output I wrote would be the matched groups. E.g in Java

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(THE_REGEX_STR);
Matcher m = p.matcher("'''la''la', 1,3");
if (m.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
}

Should print something like:
'la'la
1
3

Comment: Kobi you are right, I forgot that use case. You can have input like:<br/>
''',''thisIsValid', 1, 2<br/>
where the first string should output ','thisIsValid

Comment: grr no new line and <br/> support in comments :( sorry for that

Comment: To be honest; try to parse the values other than in a comma-seperated string. That Regex will be one hell of a regex, if it was even possible to generate such a thing.

Comment: Kobi: little mistake in my response to you, it would be also OK if it outputs '',''thisIsValid 

just the regex should be able to read it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your example strings satisfy the following regex:

```
('(''|[^'])*'|\d+)(\s*,\s*('(''|[^'])*'|\d+))*
```

Meaning:

```
(               # open group 1
  '             #   match a single quote
  (''|[^'])*    #   match two single quotes OR a single character other than a single quote, zero or more times
  '             #   match a single quote
  |             #   OR
  \d+           #   match one or more digits
)               # close group 1
(               # open group 3
  \s*,\s*       #   match a comma possibly surrounded my white space characters
  (             #   open group 4
    '           #     match a single quote
    (''|[^'])*  #     match two single quotes OR a single character other than a single quote, zero or more times
    '           #     match a single quote
    |           #     OR
    \d+         #     match one or more digits
  )             #   close group 4
)*              # close group 3 and repeat it zero or more times
```

A small demo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main { 

    public static List<String> tokens(String line) {
        if(!line.matches("('(''|[^'])*'|\\d+)(\\s*,\\s*('(''|[^'])*'|\\d+))*")) {
            return null;
        }
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("'(''|[^'])*+'|\\d++").matcher(line);
        List<String> tok = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(m.find()) tok.add(m.group());
        return tok;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests = {
                "1, 2, 3",
                "'a', 'b',    'c'",
                "'a','b','c'",
                "1, 'a', 'b'",
                "'this''is''one string', 1, 2",
                "'''this'' is a weird one', 1, 2",
                "'''''''', 1, 2",
                /* and some invalid ones */
                "''', 1, 2",
                "1 2, 3, 4, 'aaa'",
                "'a', 'b', 'c"
        };
        for(String t : tests) {
            System.out.println(t+" --tokens()--> "+tokens(t));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3 --tokens()--> [1, 2, 3]
'a', 'b',    'c' --tokens()--> ['a', 'b', 'c']
'a','b','c' --tokens()--> ['a', 'b', 'c']
1, 'a', 'b' --tokens()--> [1, 'a', 'b']
'this''is''one string', 1, 2 --tokens()--> ['this''is''one string', 1, 2]
'''this'' is a weird one', 1, 2 --tokens()--> ['''this'' is a weird one', 1, 2]
'''''''', 1, 2 --tokens()--> ['''''''', 1, 2]
''', 1, 2 --tokens()--> null
1 2, 3, 4, 'aaa' --tokens()--> null
'a', 'b', 'c --tokens()--> null
```

But, can't you simply use an existing (and proven) CSV parser instead? [Ostermiller's CSV parser](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html) comes to mind.

Comment: That matches the whole line, but your first group `('(''|[^'])*'|\d+)` does the trick (for me at least)

Comment: thanks for the response. yes it does match the examples but my point is to read out the values in groups.

Comment: Ah yes, I though you simply wanted to validate the lines. See my edited answer how to get the values from the line (if the line is properly formed!).

Comment: <grumble>Those Christmas advertisements come earlier each year!</grumble> ;)

Comment: Hai, Friends. I need one help for, how to check  (F(1) = 44) this type of pattern will be occured or not in a paragraph.   Note: Inside of open close will have must integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem that you have an input list that is guaranteed to be in the format you showed here, and you just need to split it out into individual items? For that, you probably don't need a regular expression at all.

If the strings can't contain commas, just split on comma to get your individual tokens. Then for the tokens that aren't numbers, remove the start/ending quote. Then replace '' with '. Problem solved, no regex required.

Comment: As elaborated in the question's comments, it appears that strings *can* contain commas.

Comment: And in case, a string may contain commas, you just have to implement a custom split method to detect the 'string' types, then proceed as Brian suggested. No regexp needed.

Comment: Interestingly enough, however, the regex involved isn't actually that complicated. See my answer for a fairly simple one.

Comment: sorry if I was not clear enough. The string can contain commas. e.g 'hel,lo' OR 'hel'',''lo' OR ',''hello' OR any other weird combination you can imagine.

Comment: well, Andreas_D, I don't think that a custom split function to find the tokens would be a trivial task. Given that commas are allowed, I think a regex is exactly the right solution for the problem. Although I second Bart's suggestion of checking out an existing CSV parser library first (not sure if the one he linked likes the format Bob has of single quotes and escaping quotes with quotes, so it might not be the right choice).

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off doing this as a two-step process; first break it into fields, then post-process the content of each field.

```
\s*('(?:''|[^'])*'|\d+)\s*(?:,|$)
```

Should match a single field. Then just iterate through each match (by alternating `.find()` and then `.group(1)`) to grab each field in order. You can convert double-apostrophes into singles after pulling the field value out; just do a simple string replace for `''` -> `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Matching quoted strings with RegExp is a difficult proposition.  It's helpful for you that your delimiter text isn't just a single quote, but in fact it's a single quote plus one of: comma, start of line, end of line.  This means the only time that back-to-back single quotes appear in a legitimate entry will be as part of string escaping.

Writing a regexp to match this isn't too hard for success cases, but for failure cases it can become very challenging.

It might be in your best interests to sanitize the text before matching it.  Replace all `\` instances with a literal `\u005c` then all `''` instances with a literal `\u0027` (in that order).  You're providing a level of escaping here which leaves a string with no particular special characters.

Now you can use a simple pattern such as `(?:(?:^\s*|\s*,\s*)(?:'([^']*)'|[^,]*?)))*\s*$`

Here's a breakdown of that pattern (for clarity, I use the terminology 'set' to indicate non-capturing grouping, and 'group' to indicate capturing grouping):

```
(?:               Open a non-capturing / alternation set 1
  (?:             Open a non-capturing / alternation set 2
    ^\s*          Match the start of the line and any amount of white space.
    |             alternation (or) for alternation set 2
    \s*,\s*       A comma surrounded by optional whitespace
  )               Close non-capturing group 2 (we don't care about the commas once we've used them to split our data)
  (?:             Open non-capturing set 3
    '([^']*)'     Capturing group #1 matching the quoted string value option.
    |             alternation for set 3.
    ([^,]*?)      Capturing group #2 matching non-quoted entries but not including a comma (you might refine this part of the expression if for example you only want to allow numbers to be non-quoted).  This is a non-greedy match so that it'll stop at the first comma rather than the last comma.
  )               Close non-capturing set 3
)                 Close non-capturing set 1
*                 Repeat the whole set as many times as it takes (the first match will trigger the ^ start of line, the subsequent matches will trigger the ,comma delimiters)
\s*$              Consume trailing spaces until the end of line.
```

Your quoted parameters will be in capturing group 1, your non-quoted parameters will be in capturing group 2.  Everything else will be discarded.

Then loop over the matched entries and reverse the encoding (replace `\u0027` with `'`, and `\u005c` with `\` in that order), and you're done.

This should be fairly fault tolerant and correctly parse some obtuse technically incorrect but recoverable scenarios such as `1, a''b, 2` but still fail on unrecoverable values such as `1, a'b, 2`, while succeeding on the technically correct (but probably unintentional) entry `1, 'ab, 2'`